# Safe access operator (&.) gives an "undefined local variable or method for #<Api::V1::Controller:x123abc>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get the `name` property from the first one among the values corresponding to some keys in `params` that I try to get it from.

In my console this works:

```
company = Company.find_by_id(params[:company_id])
contract = Contract.find_by_id(params[:contract_id])

company&.name || contract&.company&.name || "Default Text"
```

but when I run it, I get an error. Here's the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `name' for #<Api::V1::ReportsController:0x007fb7e2570660>
```

I looks like it's just trying to access the varible/method `name`, rather than trying to access it from `company`, `contract.company`, or `nil`. Any reason why this might happen? Also why would it happen in the controller, but not the console?

Comment: Must be it happens elsewhere. A controller helper method called from a view, or something. This code looks fine.

Comment: Why do you think it is this code that raises the error?

Comment: Can you share the complete backtrace?

Comment: What ruby version are you running?

Comment: @FrederikSpang 2.4.0

Comment: Hi, I think you've defined variable or method as a "name" or the model "company" have not field called "name". Please do check it, also check the name is being called elsewhere.

Comment: @Asmita It shouldn't matter if the variable `name` is defined elsewhere. The only thing that matters is that company has an attribute `name`, which it does, and that `contract` has an attribute `company`, which it does.

Comment: @PeterR Is above code from `ReportsController `?  Also would you please share more code?

Comment: @Asmita Yes, it is in the ReportsController. What code would you like to see more of? The Controller code?

Comment: @PeterR Yes, The controller code.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to a typo. Make sure you wrote:

`contract&.company&.name`, not `contract&.company.&name`

The `.&name` typo would raise that very same "undefined local variable or method" error you're encountering.